# ProxyProvider - Struggling using it to return List<int>

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

i'm new to flutter and i'm trying to use ProxyProvider to return List depending on List
here's the code in main.dart

```
providers: [
        FutureProvider<List<Mixer>>(
            create: (_) => mixerdbService.retrieveMixers(),
            initialData: <Mixer>[]),
        ProxyProvider<List<Mixer>, List<int>>(update: (_, mixers, __) {
          final List<int> ints = [];

          for (var mixer in mixers) {
            shipmentdbService
                .retrieveNumberOfShipmentsByMixerId(mixer.id)
                .then((value) => ints.add(value));
          }
          return ints;
        }),
```

and this the method retrieveNumberOfShipmentsByMixerId

```
  Future<int> retrieveNumberOfShipmentsByMixerId(String? mixerId) async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = await _db
        .collection("shipments")
        .where("mixer_id", isEqualTo: mixerId)
        .get();
    return snapshot.docs.length;
  }
```

The provider value is an empty list.
i think that there is a mistake in the logic in update method of the proxyprovider.
if the question is not clear, please ask me for more details

## Solution

### step#1

```
        FutureProvider<List<Mixer>>(
            create: (_) => mixerdbService.retrieveMixers(),
            initialData: <Mixer>[]),
        ProxyProvider<List<Mixer>, Future<List<int>>>(
            update: (_, mixers, __) async {
          final List<int> ints = [];

          for (var mixer in mixers) {
            final value = await shipmentdbService
                .retrieveNumberOfShipmentsByMixerId(mixer.id);
            ints.add(value);
          }
          return ints;
        }),
```

### step#2: Resolve the Future from the Provider by using FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
        future: context.read<Future<List<int>>>(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData &&
              snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty &&
              listOfMixers.isNotEmpty) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listOfMixers.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return MixerCard(
                      mixer: listOfMixers[index],
                      numberOfShipments: snapshot.data![index]);
                });
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
```

This solution is okay, but i'm still searching for another solution without the use of FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `ProxyProvider` is returning a list that's not populated yet because of the async calls with `.then`.

To solve it return a `Future<List<int>>` instead and make the update function `async`. It's going to be like below:

```dart
ProxyProvider<List<Mixer>, Future<List<int>>>(
    update: (_, mixers, __) async {
  final List<int> ints = [];

  for (var mixer in mixers) {
    final value = await shipmentdbService
        .retrieveNumberOfShipmentsByMixerId(mixer.id);
    ints.add(value);
  }
  return ints;
}),
```

### Solution 1

Then add another `FutureProvider` like so:

```dart
FutureProvider<List<int>>(
  create: (context) => context.read<Future<List<int>>>(),
  initialData: [],
),
```

This way it's easy to use it like:

```dart
final listOfMixers = context.watch<List<Mixer>>();
final listOfInts = context.watch<List<int>>();
return Scaffold(
  body: listOfMixers.isNotEmpty && listOfInts.isNotEmpty   // <- Here
      ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listOfMixers.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return MixerCard(
              mixer: listOfMixers[index],
              numberOfShipments: listOfInts[index],
            );
          })
      : const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
);
```

### Solution 2

Or use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to get the `List<int>` out of the `Future`. Something like the following:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
  future: context.read<Future<List<int>>>(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return ErrorPage();
    }

    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    final listLengths = snapshot.data;
    // Do something with `listLengths`
  }),
```

Comment: @Iepsch can i use FutureProvider with the other two providers to provider the List<int> ?

Comment: You would need something like a `FutureProxyProvider`, but unfortunately, this doesn't exist. I'd recommend using `FutureBuilder` as you have the error state if something goes wrong. You can also return a `Provider<List<int>>` inside the `FutureBuilder` so you have the `List<int>>` available on the providers. Something like `return Provider(create: (_) => listLengths, child: ...the_app...);`

Comment: I've added another solution to the answer (Solution 1). Please take a look.

Comment: i tried solution one before you edited your answer, but it didn't work. the returned listOfInts is empty, and trying to use it giving RangeError (index) Invalid value: Valid value range is empty

Comment: this didn't solve the issu too , still the list is empty and the CircularProgressIndicator spinning forever

Comment: here is the debugPring output `   I/flutter ( 3461): list of Mixers is[Instance of 'Mixer', Instance of 'Mixer', Instance of 'Mixer', Instance of 'Mixer']
I/flutter ( 3461): list of Integers is[] `

Comment: Did you figure it out already?

Comment: YES, thanks @Iepsch Solution2 Woked, but still searching for another design without using FutureBuilder because it misses the UI and I want to use listOfInt in another places. but the solution is Okay for now.